# Is writing tests after development an example of extreme programming?

Tags: testing

Is this an example of extreme programming? Currently we try to write all tests before development is done, but at times it is done afterwards when there are time constraints.

Comment: Nope. Post hoc testing is Extremely Sloppy Programming™. Even in traditional waterfall, you're supposed to do QA and UAT before delivery. Q.E.D.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How TDD is related to extreme programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149798/how-tdd-is-related-to-extreme-programming)

Comment: Do yourself a favor and pick up a copy of “Extreme Programming Explained” by Kent Beck. It’s very approachable, whether or not you’re a technical person.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, no it's not an example of XP. Delivering untested code is just sloppy.

Different practices have different opinions about *when* test are to be written.

But they all agree on one thing: *After release* is **too late**.

Comment: Ah right, what should you do then if you are running out of time, it works, but cannot write tests?

Comment: How do you know it "works" when you don't have tests? Tests are not something that you tack on top because a book says they are nice... tests are functionally necessary to come to the conclusion you already seem to have. So when you run out of time, you deliver without tests and hope your customer does not know it's sloppy. Then you improve your process so you don't run out of time next time.

Comment: @bobo2000: How can you say that it works if it hasn't been tested?

Comment: You can do manual testing

Comment: Unless you don't have to rerun tests, manual testing will likely take longer than writing tests. One bug will invalidate your manual testing.  It may take a little longer to get started using automated tests, but it pays off quickly.

Comment: TDD/BDD has it's limitations though, does not spot styling issues.

Answer (score 1):

- Test Driven Development is a [rule](http://www.extremeprogramming.org/rules/testfirst.html) in eXtreme Programming.
- Test Driven Development requires that tests must be written first.
- Therefore, the answer is, "NO."